# String ambiguous constructor (byte[] vs char[])

Tags: java, string, constructor, char, byte

This is not an issue but I am trying to understand the fundamental nuance here.

While constructing String (with `new String(arg)`)  where `arg` is either `char[]` or `byte[]`, I am getting follwing error:
 `The constructor String(byte[]) is ambiguous` 
I checked String implementation of `Java version 8` and found two constructors: 
`public String(byte[] data) {`
`public String(char[] data) {`

if I am passing `char[]`, why does it match to constructor with argument `byte[]`?
and if I am passing `byte[]`, why does it match to constructor with argument `char[]`?
Does it match because of the size in bytes? (which could be same in both cases with `UTF-8` encoding?)

**Edit 1:**
`arg` in discussion here is one value of a map `HashMap<Serializable, Serializable>()` which is built from `HttpServletRequest` received from client.

**Edit 2:**
I managed to reproduce it as best as I could.

This code works:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTest t = new StringTest();
        System.out.println((String)(t.getParameter("Hello"))); 

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Serializable> T getParameter(Serializable key) {
        return (T)new String("Hello");
    }
}
```

However this does not:

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTest t = new StringTest();
        System.out.println(new String(t.getParameter("Hello")));        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Serializable> T getParameter(Serializable key) {
        return (T)new String("Hello");
    }
}
```

[image: String class getting ambiguous constructor]

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Note also that "X is ambiguous" messages typically say all of the ambiguous options - have you included the entire message?

Comment: Executing both `new String(new char[0]);` and `new String(new byte[0]);` works fine. What´s the problem?

Comment: passing exact type does not have an issue. Added more details to understand it better.

Comment: Are you using some of kind of dodgy serialisation framework here?

Comment: I am using Java serialization here

Comment: @AndyTurner I added code samples

Comment: There is no ambiguity between `byte[]` and `char[]`. As your `getParameter()` method always returns a `String` it is hard to see why you are trying to made it generic.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am not asking for a solution but rather trying to understand the difference between both approach. This sample code is just a tiny part of larger enterprise wide project, so displayed context here is limited.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a method that validates the `Serializable` type and then cast the instance to access the related constructor of `String`.

```
public String parse(Serializable s) {
    if (s instanceof char[]) {
        return new String((char[]) s);
    }
    if (s instanceof byte[]) {
        return new String((byte[]) s);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + s.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however, I just wanted to take the value received from the map mentioned in the question and convert it to String and I could easily do it with typecasting.. such as "(String) arg". Looks like there is a difference between typecasting to String and Constructing a String with default constructors in this context. I just wanted to know that difference.

Comment: My assumptions was based on your `Map` containing `char[]` and `byte[]`. Both are not an instance of `String`, or what did you mean with casting to it?